when the github actions is triggered, it shows the error
I am a relatively new Terraform(GCP) user and I currently running into some problems when using github actions.
I am trying to implement CI/CD using github actions - when the github actions is triggered, it shows the error, as an example:
Error: open ./terra2.zip: no such file or directory
I have tried:

Uploading the file to a GCP Bucket, and using the "gs://" link
Uploading the file to Github Repo, and using names such as "./terra2.zip", "terra2.zip", ".\\terra2.zip"

I was expecting the resource could get the file, however, it doesn't seem like that's the case
Here is the code with the error:
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "function_source" {
  name   = "terra2.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.source_files_production.name
  source = "./terra2.zip"
}


Is the zip file on the same directory level as the terraform code? Are you specifying where (i.e, directory) the init, plan and apply steps should happen?

yes i have checked on it and change the code to ../.. to the root and it works Thanks @MarkoE !

You need to zip your github repo's folder and then move/copy into s3 bucket:
    - name: Zip the folder
      run: |
        zip -r my-folder.zip /path/to/your/folder

    - name: Upload to GCP bucket
      run: |
        gsutil cp my-folder.zip gs://your-gcp-bucket-name/

